# Trouble displaying inline forms of a ModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-admin

I am encountering what seems to me a weird bug when rendering Inline forms on the "Add" view of a `ModelAdmin`.

Here is a minimum example with Django version `2.2.4`.

---

in `models.py`:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class RelatedModel(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, null=False, blank=False)
```

in `admin.py`:

```py
class RelatedModelInlineTabular(admin.TabularInline):
    model = RelatedModel
    show_change_link = False
    fields = ("number", )

class TestMyModelCreate(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['text', ]
    inlines = [RelatedModelInlineTabular]

admin.site.register(MyModel, TestMyModelCreate)
```

#### Steps to replicate

- Login to django admin website
- open the "add" view for `MyModel` (i.e. navigate to the list of Models and click on the "Add new" button)

#### Expected result

The form displays an empty text field. Below that, an Inline form is displayed with 3 empty rows for potential related instances of `RelatedModel`

#### Actual result

The Inline form is displayed twice, each instance with its own 3 empty rows, as if I had specified it twice.

---

I attach a screenshot below of the actual page (`Discount` is the name of the related Model). I tried and I get the same result with both `StackedInline` and `TabularInline`.

Am I making some trivial error here that could explain what's happening? Or is this is a known bug? Thank you in advance to anyone that will help.

[image: something's off here]